# Comparing values in columns row by row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]
I have the following data table and would like to look at each ticker value (there are 8032 unique types) and add the b_mkt (with the same TICKER) for each year and take the avg. I was wondering if there is a pandas method that would allow me to do that? Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `df.groupby(['DATE', 'TICKER'])['b_mkt'].agg(['sum', 'mean'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a groupby:

```
your_dataframe.groupby(['TICKER','DATE']).mean()
```

Edit: forgot brackets